# Smart Contract internal method return value to caller e.g. angular

Tags: ethereum-classic

Smart Contract internal method (last in chain of public view method) is able to return value at the end for parent method (public view) caller e.g. Angular?

Comment: Can you share a code example of the call? For view methods you should be able to get the return value, for transaction it is recommended to generate events when you want to obtain a value.

Comment: e.g. function doStep(bytes32 _address) public view { doFirstStep(_address); } function doFirstStep(bytes32 _address) internal { doSecondStep(_address); } function doSecondStep(bytes32 _address) internal returns (bytes32) { return(_address) }
First method "doStep"is called by Angular and response comes from internal "doSecondStep". It is possible? I havent tested it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `internal` method in chain, called by parent `public view` method **returns** given value to caller.